# Taking data from a form request and sending it off as a post request doesn't seem to work

Tags: php, html, curl, post, php-curl

This is my form (html):

```
<div class="body"> 
    <form method="post" action="index.php">
        <div id="form"> 
            <div class="formInput"> 
                <label>To: 
                <input type="text" name="to" id="to" /> 
                </label> 
            </div> 
            <div class="formInput"> 
                <label>From: 
                <input type="text" name="from" id="from" /> 
                </label> 
            </div> 
            <div class="formInput"> 
                <label>Message: 
                <input type="text" name="message" id="message" /> 
                </label> 
            </div>
            <div class="formInput"> 
                <label>Email: 
                <input type="text" name="email" id="email" /> 
                </label> 
                <div class="formInput"> 
                <label>Api_Secret: 
                <input type="text" name="api_secret" id="api_secret" /> 
                </label> 
            </div> 
            </div> 
            <input type="submit" value="Submit" /> 
        </div> 
    </form>
```

And this is my php that handles the http request using curl:

to is usually a number

from is either a number or a string

message has both numbers and strings

email is just a normal email@email.com

api_secret includes both numbers and strings.

```
<?php
$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt_array($ch, [
    CURLOPT_URL => 'https://domainname.com/dashboard/api',
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
    CURLOPT_POST => true,
    CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => [
        'to' => $_POST['to'],
        'from' => $_POST['from'],
        'message' => $_POST['message'],
        'email' => $_POST['email'],
        'api_secret' => $_POST['api_secret'],
    ],
]);

$response = curl_exec($ch);

curl_close($ch);

echo($response);
?>
```

The correct request form should look like this:

```
https://domainname.com/dashboard/api?to={PHONE NUMBER}&from={SENDER ID}&message={TEXT}&email{YOUREMAIL}&api_secret={API SECRET}
```

But it seems like nothing is being taken from the form and being sent... I tried using PostBin both the Query and Body seem empty.
I have no idea what to do or how to proceed from here.
Any help is highly appreciated.

Update:
Changed the php so it correctly posts the data:

```
<?php
$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt_array($ch, [
    CURLOPT_URL => 'https://domainname.com/dashboard/api',
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
    CURLOPT_POST => true,
    CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => [
        'to' => $_POST['to'],
        'from' => $_POST['from'],
        'message' => $_POST['message'],
        'email' => $_POST['email'],
        'api_secret' => $_POST['api_secret'],
    ],
]);

$response = curl_exec($ch);

curl_close($ch);

echo($response);
?>
```

Instead of the query looking like:

```
123&text&text2&email@email.com&123abc
```

It looks like this:

```
123:text:text2:email@email.com:123abc:
```

Comment: First var_dump($_POST) to make sure that you are receiving data.

Answer (score 0):

If this is what your API call requires, it is sending the data as parameters, not in the POST FIELDS.

```
https://domainname.com/dashboard/api?to={PHONE NUMBER}&from={SENDER ID}&message={TEXT}&email{YOUREMAIL}&api_secret={API SECRET}
```

If you need to send the values as a POST request with parameters, this is what you need.

```
$url = 'https://domainname.com/dashboard/api';
$sep = '?';
foreach(['to', 'from', 'message', 'email', 'api_secret'] as $key) {
   $url .= $sep . $key=$_POST[$key];
   if ( $sep == '?' ) $sep = '&';
}
$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt_array($ch, [
    CURLOPT_URL => $url,
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
    CURLOPT_POST => true]);
$response = curl_exec($ch);

curl_close($ch);

echo($response);
```

Comment: I appreciate your help so much, i have been trying to solve this issue for the past 3 days and im going crazy.. It looks like now data is being sent but not in the correct format. This is what the query looks like:  123:text:text2:email@email.com:123abc:

Comment: Edit the question so it reflects what you are really asking for.